# Python Numpy - Square Values Issue

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to square all the elements in a numpy array but the results are not what I'm expecting (ie some are negative numbers and none are the actual square values). Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong and/or whats going on?

```
import numpy as np
import math
f = 'file.bin'
frameNum = 25600
channelNum = 2640

data = np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int16)
total = frameNum*channelNum*2
rs = data[:total].reshape(channelNum,-1) #reshaping the data a little. Omitting added values at the end.  


I = rs[:,::2] # pull out every other column

print "Shape :", I.shape
print "I : ", I[1,:10]
print "I**2 : ", I[1,:10]**2
print "I*I : ",I[1,:10]* I[1,:10]
print "np.square : ",np.square(I[1,:10])
exit()
```

Output:

```
Shape : (2640L, 25600L)
I :  [-5302 -5500 -5873 -5398 -5536 -6708 -6860 -6506 -6065 -6363]
I**2 :  [ -3740 -27632  20193 -25116 -23552 -25968   4752  -8220  18529 -13479]
I*I :  [ -3740 -27632  20193 -25116 -23552 -25968   4752  -8220  18529 -13479]
np.square :  [ -3740 -27632  20193 -25116 -23552 -25968   4752  -8220  18529 -13479]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Surely that is just integer overflow? 16 bits won't be enough to hold a square of numbers of that magnitude

Comment: Try `data = np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int16).astype(np.int32)` to convert the values to 32 bit after reading them.  That doubles the size of the array, but if you want to square the values without overflow, you need more bits.

Comment: I don't necessary think that is the problem because if I build a small version of the array by hand it seems to work:
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: i = np.array([-5302, -5500,-5873,-5398])

    In [3]: import math

    In [4]: i*i
    Out[4]: array([28111204, 30250000, 34492129, 29138404])

Comment: In that case, `i` is not 16 bit.  Look at `i.dtype`.

Comment: Try it with ` i = np.array([-5302, -5500,-5873,-5398], dtype=np.int16)`

Comment: I take back my previous comment.  Changing to astype(np.int32) works.   Thanks Warren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the `dtype=np.int16`.   You are allowing only 16 bits to represent the numbers, and `-5302**2` is larger than the maximum value (32767) that a signed 16-bit integer can take.  So you're seeing only the lowest 16 bits of the result, the first of which is interpreted (or, from your point of view, misinterpreted) as a sign bit.

Convert your array to a different dtype - for example

```
I = np.array( I, dtype=np.int32 )
```

or

```
I = np.array( I, dtype=np.float )
```

before performing numerical operations that might go out of range.

With `dtype=np.int16`, the highest-magnitude integers you can square are +181 and -181.  The square of 182 is larger than 32767 and so it overflows.  Even with `dtype=np.int32` representation, the highest-magnitude integers you can square are +46340 and -46340: the square of 46341 overflows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason:

```
>>> a = np.array([-5302, -5500], dtype=np.int16)
>>> a * a
array([ -3740, -27632], dtype=int16)
```

This the solution:

```
b = np.array([-5302, -5500], dtype=np.int32)
>>> b * b
>>> array([28111204, 30250000], dtype=int32)
```

Change:

```
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int16)
```

into:

```
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.in16).astype(np.int32)
```